# Using multiple childFilters in Solr childDocTransformer

Tags: java, solr, lucene

Is it possible to use 2 child-doc-transformers in the 'fl' field.

***fl = "[child childFilter=level2Filter] [child childFilter=level3filter]***

Or is it possible to have 2 'childFilter' attributes within the same [child] transformer.

***fl = "[child childFilter=level2Filter childFilter = level3Filter]"***

I have a nested document of 3 level of hierarchy. I am trying to filter my documents of level 2 and level 3 in the same query.

Any help/pointers apppreciated.

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible to define 2 filters within childFilter.

You can try something like:

```
fl=[child childFilter=$levelFilter]&levelFilter=(level2Filter OR level3Filter)
```

Maybe following article would be helpful.
https://sease.io/2019/06/apache-solr-childfilter-transformer.html (search for "Complex childFilter queries")